# Parallelization of several loops

Tags: multithreading, loops, for-loop, while-loop, parallel-processing

What is the application domain should I look for in order to find several loop constructions operating on the same data? I want to find such patterns and try to parallelize them.

```
for (...) {
    work1(data);
}

for (...) {
    work2(data);
}
```

I would like to find not only simple dependencies, but more complex too.

Comment: No clue what you're asking for. Are you asking for a static analysis tool that will look at source code and identify loops that operate on the same data?

Comment: I am trying to find applications, where there are several loops going one after another and processing the same data, so I could introduce inter-loop parallelism.

Comment: So you're looking for a static analysis tool. Depending on how automated you want it, you might be able to do it with Visual Studio's "Find References" functionality, or ReSharper might be able to help. If you want to write a program to do it, you'll want to look into [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx).

Comment: I actually want to find applications where there are such loops as above so I could test my own analysis tool.